# Connect zoul mote to local mqtt broker in contiki

Tags: ipv6, mqtt, mosquitto, contiki

I am trying to connect my zoul motes to my local broker(mosquitto with default settings) using the rpl border router in contiki os
I used the following files `examples/ipv6/rpl-border-router/border-router.c` and `examples/cc2538-common/mqtt-demo/mqtt-demo.c` to make rpl border router and mqtt sample.
I just want to know how to do it because i cannot even connect to rpl border router (I can see if the second mote with mqtt sample has ipv6 address or not in rpl border router's web interface).
and do i need to setup NAT64 for that?

Comment: when connecting to rpl border router for a long time this message is getting displayed: `slip-bridge: Destination off-link but no route src=aaaa::1 dst=aaaa::212:4b00:615:991e`, and the ip address of the mote that holds mqtt sample is displayed also in rpl border router web interface.  
but still no results

Comment: You hardly provide any useful information to help you further, what IPv6 prefix are you using (my guess is the `aaaa::/64` from your comment)? is the MQTT node showing at the BR's webserver or not?  What does your relevant `project-conf.f` or `Makefile` looks like?